# Использование неопределенного типа, хотя упреждающее объявление есть

Tags: c++, дружественная-функция

Стивен Пратта язык программирования C++ страница 812, листинг 15.4
visual studio 2022
прям с книжки заполнил, но почему то когда с открытого enum использую значение, то пишет что необъявленный идентификатор. то есть TV/Tv::TV неизвестен, хотя класс объявлен за ранее, что бы был виден Remot'у. И пытался в отдельном заголовочном файле делать, но ошибка та же самая.

```
class Tv;
class Remote {
private:
    int mode; 
    public:
    Remote(int m = TV); //прям с книги, но IDE ругается: "идентификатор не определен"
    ...   //заменил на Tv::TV ругается уже компилятор: "необъявленный идентификатор"
};
        
class Tv {
    //friend class Remote;
    friend void Remote::set_ch(Tv& t, int c);
public:
    enum{TV, DVD};
    ...
};
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему такое может происходить?

Comment: Все правильно `class Tv;` объявлен, что внутри этого класса - нет.

Comment: Компилятор читает код сверху вниз. К моменту, когда он видит `int m = TV`, он еще не видел `enum{TV, DVD}`. (Есть исключения, тело каждого отдельного класса компилятор смотрит дважды, откладывая на второй проход тела функций. Но здесь это не помогает.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если посмотреть листинг 15.4 из упомянутой вами книги *полностью*, то можно обнаружить, что класс `Remote` тоже имеет перечислимое значение `TV`:

```
class Remote {
public:
    enum State {Off, On};
    enum {MinVal, MaxVal=20};
    enum {Antenna, Cable}      //В моём экземпляре книги точка с запятой здесь отсутствует, хотя должна быть.
    enum {TV, VCR};
private:
    int mode; 
public:
    Remote(int m = TV) : mode(m){}
};
```

Получается, значение `TV`, принимаемое по умолчанию для параметра конструктора `m`, берётся из класса `Remote`, а не `Tv`.

Comment: да, точно, спасибо за помощь, как говорится смотрю в книгу вижу фигу. Был не внимателен.